# Equation involving summations and complex exponentials

Tags: sequences-and-series, ordinary-differential-equations, summation, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

## Solve for $C_k$

$$\sum _{k=-\infty }^{\infty } \frac{i (-1)^k e^{i k t}}{k}=4 \sum _{k=-\infty }^{\infty } k^2 C_k \left(-e^{i k t}\right)+4 \sum _{k=-\infty }^{\infty } i k C_k e^{i k t}+17 \sum _{k=-\infty }^{\infty } C_k e^{i k t}$$

The first thing I noticed was that both **LHS** and **RHS** has the factor $e^{ikt}$ attached in their respective summation terms. Therefore we can safely remove this from our equation:

$$\sum _{k=-\infty }^{\infty } \frac{i (-1)^k}{k}=-4 \sum _{k=-\infty }^{\infty } k^2 C_k+4 i \sum _{k=-\infty }^{\infty } k C_k+17 \sum _{k=-\infty }^{\infty } C_k$$

---

I'm stuck here, any idea what I can do next to solve for $C_k$. I'm not *too* familiar with summation marks, and what rules there are to them, but I'd like to cancel them out if possible. Notice they're all in the same range, $[-\infty,\infty]$.

Comment: The sums on the LHS do not converge.  (Note $k=0$ term.)

Comment: Oh yes, $k$ is supposed to be limited from 0. So $k\not=0$; does this suffice to prevent the problem you mentioned?

Answer (score 1):

You can't just cancel a term like that! Thats because the $\Sigma$ is more like a function than a multiplier, and just because say $\sin(\cos(x) x) = \sin(\cos (x) 2x)$ for some $x$, doesn't mean you can conclude that $\sin(x) = \sin(2x)$ for this same $x$. For further confirmation, try it for a small sum. $\sum_{k=1}^2 e^{ikt} = \sum_{k=1}^2 k C_k e^{ikt}$

What you can do, is compare coefficients of each $e^{ikt}$. This is allowed because they form a basis.

So we have

$$\frac{i (-1)^k e^{i k t}}{k}=4  k^2 C_k \left(-e^{i k t}\right)+4 i k C_k e^{i k t}+17  C_k e^{i k t}$$

**Now** you can cancel the $e^{ikt}$s, and then rearrange for $C_k$.

(edit- Ron Gordon's comment raises an important point, but the method I have lined out above is still correct)

Comment: Ok, I'd love to learn more about the theory in summation, it hasn't been taught so far in my education. I need to ask though, the reason we can compare coefficients, is as you said because they form a basis, but we wouldn't be able to do this if the ranges for the summations weren't the same, right?

Comment: Well it would be impossible for them to be equal if the ranges were not the same, due to `linear independence' (the same holds in our infinite dimensional space). So yeah, you wouldn't be able to. 

Another example would be finding say $c$ such that $x = cx^3$; its just not possible.

Comment: ${c} = {\frac {1}{x^2}}$ :P What about ${\sum _{k=0}^{n} k} = {\sum _{k=n}^{n} {\frac{{xk}{(k+1)}}{2}}}$? We can solve giving ${x} = {1}$

Comment: $c$ being a constant. As for the second I don't understand it because I can't read the sums sorry ._.

Comment: @CalvinKhor sum of natural numbers, and a sum with only one term, namely the formula for the sum of the natural numbers, times x

Comment: Well you don't have any basis elements to talk about in that sum so all bets are off. In the OP we are using the trigonometric polynomials $\{ e^{ikt}\}$ and in $x = cx^3$ we are thinking of the monomials $\{1,x,x^2,x^3,\dots\}$ as a basis say of $L^2$ on an interval. Since $x$ and $x^3$ are linearly independent, the only $c_1,c_2$ such that $c_1x + c_2x^3 = 0$ is $c_1=c_2=0$.